# Why does adding something to a dictionary break deleting messages in discord.py? (404 error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that deletes certain words when they are typed. I'd done this successfully, so I wanted to make a command that tells me who said the words and what words were said. So, I tried to add a line of code that adds a entry to an empty dictionary (called "who") which includes the users name and what forbidden word they said (`who[word] = str(message.author)`). This, however, causes the bot to print the same message (that appears when a forbidden word is said) multiple times, and the shell outputs an error:

> discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

The relevant bits of my code:

```
swears = ['a', 'bunch', 'of', 'really', 'bad', 'words']
who = {}


@noodle.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.channel.is_nsfw():
        for word in swears:
            if message.content.lower().find(word) != -1:
                user = noodle.get_user('''a trusted user's id''')
                await message.channel.send(f'Don't say that. {message.author.mention}, {user.mention}')
                await message.delete()
                who[word] = str(message.author)
    await noodle.process_commands(message)
```

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: Can you try adding the word to dictionary before deleting the message?

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. It seems that if I put the line `who[word] = str(message.author)` anywhere in that event block it breaks

Comment: So it should be breaking on the `message.channel.send` since that has a mention to `message.author` ?

Comment: I guess so, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: No idea actually, have little clue about how async-await works in python (I'd assume similar to JS but can't guarantee). Try this: remove the message.delete() and see if it works without that.

Comment: I figured it out, I'm typing up a reply to my own question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was being really dumb. I would delete this question but I think I should keep it up if anyone else is having the same issues. I run the bot on Heroku, which lets you host bots for free on servers 24/7. For some reason, I thought that running my python script would override the Heroku one. Of course, it didn't do that, and I effectively had 2 bots running at the same time doing the exact same thing. This explained the stacked replies, as well as the error because the Heroku script deleted the message before the one from my local machine, so my one tried to delete a message that was already deleted, which of course brought up an error.

Comment: Ohh, well it's usually the simplest mistake which causes us to break our head :)